# Is it possible - a hybrid 15“ Macbook (2011) with a 13” MAcbook motherboard?

Tags: mac, motherboard, macbook

I have a 2011 15" MacBook Pro with a useless logic board. The rest of the laptop is fine, at least it was the last time it was used several years ago. I also have a 13" MacBook, also a 2011 model. This was given to me. It has been dropped by it's former owner, so is a bit bent out of shape, he had also spilled a mug of coffee over it destroying the keyboard (it works fine with a USB keyboard and the onboard disabled), and it overheated at some point leaving some soft burn marks in the screen (likely the diffuser layer). Motherboard is perfectly fine.

So, is it possible to take the good 13" motherboard and install it into my 15" MacBook effectively downgrading it, but restoring it to usable condition?

Comment: Sounds like the kind of project you could spend an afternoon trialling...

Comment: Are they both Macbook Pro motherboards?

Comment: Both are Pro motherboards. My question is more to do with things like all the connectors being compatible or not? i.e. the battery, the LCD screen, the onboard keyboard, etc

Comment: I just made the attempt. Maybe 70% of plugs are in the correct positions, but a few key plugs are not. Battery and Keyboard cables are in opposite positions, and a few other plugs though in correct positions are rotated 90 degrees. In all those situations there is not enough cable length to compensate. So, for now, I've just swapped the DVD-ROM over so that at least of I have working unit in the 13"model.

Comment: If I go ahead with this I think something more radical will be needed, such as making a new case, perhaps out of acrylic (and filling it with fancy LED lights just for the hell of it!) carefully cutting the the old unit apart and rearranging it into a new case. I might still have issues with cable lengths though, but I've got little to lose in trying, so if I feel brave enough to attempt this rebuild I'll update you here, as for now, there's nothing more I can do.